# What is the model/year of a white and yellow airplane with a sticker "96" on the wing?

Tags: set-identification

I found this airplane in a bag at Goodwill, but not sure what set it's from. It looks complete and the landing gear pulls down. 
Any idea what year or set this is from?

[image: airplane 96 sticker]

[image: photo from above] [image: close-up] [image: side view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [42044-1: Display Team Jet](https://brickset.com/sets/42044-1/Display-Team-Jet) from 2016.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast/accurate information!